# What is the correct include path for ESP-IDF?

Tags: path, include, esp32, modbus, esp-idf

OS: Win10.
Some time ago I've installed ESP-IDF [with offline installer](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp-idf/). Integrated with VScode, worked with it, built and flashed some WiFi examples. All was good.

Then a bit later, I've installed the ESP8266 devkit as instructed [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/windows-setup.html)
Tinkered with it a bit, then went back to ESP-IDF. All was working fine.

Then today, I've opened an official ESP-IDF modbus_master example, and noticed that some (in fact a lot) of #include components have a strange filepath:
[image]

Additionally, VScode c/c++ extension indicates that official modbus_master example has the include path errors:

[image]

Of course, it does not compile.

What is the reason for ESP8266 SDK "intruded" onto ESP-IDF territory in the VScode? HOW COULD IT ADD THE FILEPATHS TO #INCLUDES inside msys2? I did not do any of that myself, so it remains a mystery.

Also, any way to fix the "include file not found" and "mbcontroller.h: No such file or directory" errors? These must stem from incorrect env. variable or filepath somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'd just tell you to re-install ESP-IDF. I'm not sure about the default path for the offline installer, but from what I remember, both install their respective toolchains and examples into the same folders and use the same ESP-IDF path variable, if you don't change them.